# Monitor Endpoint using Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, health-monitoring

I'm trying to find an out-of-the-box health check for my spring app. However, I can only find support for Spring Actuator. I'm not able to use Spring Actuator because my application is a Spring application and not a Spring boot app. Is there another library that I could make use of without having to write my own? I would ideally want an endpoint that could possibly give me data about whether my DB is up and possibly some of the java opts passed into that particular node

Comment: Spring Boot is Spring... The actuator is nothing more then preconfigured classes. Check the `@Configuration` classes and what is being loaded and you can use the actuator in a plain Spring project.

Comment: @M.Deinum would you be able to elaborate more on how to configure this?

Comment: I'm somewhat new to spring and only know that I would need to add the actuator dependency to my maven pom. What other configuration would I need to do? Would there be some config I would add to my ApplicationContext.xml file?

Comment: Yes. As mentioned Spring Boot is (mostly) a lot of auto configuration which means `@Configuration` classes preconfigured for certain parts. The actuator has also those classes... Just check the sources.